# Amcharts zoom in and zoom out for radar chart

Tags: amcharts

Is there a way to add zoom in and zoom out for radar charts in amcharts plugin apart from XY charts am not able to find that option for other type of charts specifically for radar chart.

Comment: No, radar charts don't support zoom methods or a scrollbar. XY, serial and stock charts do.

Comment: Thanks xorspark...